# how to get all possible combinations of different lengths of all list items without using itertools Python

Tags: python, list, combinations

I need to make all possible combinations of any length of list items without using itertools.

- Example: list = [1,2,3]
- Output: [[1],[2],[3],[1,2],[1,3],[2,3],[1,2,3]] ( not necessarily in lexicographical order)

I have this code:

```
def get_combination(list_of_ palindrome):

res = [list_of_palindrome[i: j] for i in the range (len(list_of_palindrome)) for j in the range (i + 1, len(list_of_palindrome) + 1)] 

return res
```

Output: `[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2], [2, 3], [3]]`

Comment: To the person who closed, OP did specify **without using `itertools`** and the top few (all?) answers of linked duplicate are *all* using `itertools`...

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/54480126/4871001 -- that's a sol'n without using itertools

Comment: If input is not unique then output may not be unique either, of course this may or may not be a problem but just in case it matter it is worth specifying.

Comment: `def allComb(A):  return [A[:1],*(A[:1]+c for c in allComb(A[1:])),*allComb(A[1:])] if A else []`

Comment: @JoshuaVoskamp if there are valid solutions to a problem without using itertools, and there's an established existing Q&A that is the canonical but lacks answers with those solutions, this should be addressed by **adding those answers** to the canonical (or offering a bounty to get others to do it).